# Deploying a full-stack application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, hosting

Could anyone give me tips on deploying my full-stack project? The project consists of a client made from React, a server made with Express, and MongoDB as my database. This is my first time deploying an application that has a server and a client running separately, so I am a bit confused about how to do it.

I currently use render.com to deploy my projects but the problem is that the server runs down after 15 minutes of inactivity with the free version, so if someone was to access my client/react static site the server would not run. Are there any other websites you would recommend for deploying that would fix this problem that are free ( I am a broke college student) or solutions to activate the backend server when the static site is activated?

Comment: Is it for real users or just for learning and fun? Your question is not for stackoverflow, so it will be closed soon.

Comment: try heroku or digitalocean or firebase

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can dockerize your applications and find a hosting site with docker so you can put your images there.